# Changing graph line colour

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph using OS X and this is what I've got:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
x_series = [22,25,28,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
y_series = [113800,101800,87000,78700,61800,49900,39700,32800,25900,21500,17500,14300,11900,9800,8300,6900,5600,4900]
plt.title("Temperature variation of resistance")
plt.xlabel("Temperature(degrees celcius)")
plt.ylabel("Resistance(ohms)")
y_sig = ([100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.])
plt.errorbar(x_series,y_series,y_sig)
```

All I want to do is change the graph line colour, to contrast against the error bar.  Any help would be appreciated; anything I've read online so far hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`plt.errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) the color of the line and error bars can be controlled by the keyword-arguments `color` and `ecolor`, respectively.

The modified code below will set the line color to black and the error color to red.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

x_series = [22,25,28,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
y_series = [113800,101800,87000,78700,61800,49900,39700,32800,25900,21500,17500,14300,11900,9800,8300,6900,5600,4900]

plt.title("Temperature variation of resistance")
plt.xlabel("Temperature(degrees celcius)")
plt.ylabel("Resistance(ohms)")

y_sig = ([100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.])

plt.errorbar(x_series,y_series,y_sig, color='black', ecolor='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]